# How to deal with empty response in axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I use `axios` with `vue.js` to fetch data as unlimited pagination. It works fine expect when there is no data to render:

```
 fetchData() {
     this.loading = true
     this.page++;
     axios.get(this.BASE_URL + '/api/jokes/'+'?page='+this.page).then( 
     response => 
     //how to exist  if there is no data in the response?
      this.jokes = response.data).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

I'm wondering how to stop rendering when we reached to the last page and there is no more data to display?

I've looked at the [docs](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) but could not find my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe introducing some basic flag logics. I have taken the freedom to assume, but you can always define your logic

```
fetchData() {
    this.loading = true;
    if (this.page > 0) {
        axios.get(this.BASE_URL + '/api/jokes/page=' + this.page)
            .then(response => {
                const isDataAvailable = response.data && response.data.length;
                this.jokes = isDataAvailable ? response.data : [];
                this.page = isDataAvailable ? (this.page + 1) : 0;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I don't want to rewrite the whole function. Please limit your answer to breaking the function when response.data is empty.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw a custom error that will be catch by the catch method.

```
 fetchData() {
 this.loading = true
 this.page++;
 axios.get(this.BASE_URL + '/api/jokes/'+'?page='+this.page).then( 
 response => {
   //how to exist  if there is no data in the response?
   if (!response.data || response.data.length == 0) {
     const emptyDataError = new Error('Invalid data');
     emptyDataError.statusCode = 500;
     throw emptyDataError;
   }
   this.jokes = response.data;
 }).catch(function (error) {
   console.log(error);
 });
```